# price field is not working in wo-commerce on change

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When price filter widget is added in woo-commerce sidebar it is displayed in sidebar. it shows price range correctly. But when I tried to access price in custom range and click filter it shows page not found error. why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer for the problem with product price filter. change the paramlinks to post type or any other type and save. then price filter will start working.